# Code inside of powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden not working, powershell skips it

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell code that runs on around 100 computers, but on three specific computers it skips everything inside of the powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden { }

I run a test using the code below on powershell Ise

```
powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden {
write-host "test"
}
write-host "test2"
```

Both test texts were shown on console, but when I try to run

```
powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden {
write-host "test"
write-host "test1"
}
write-host "test2"
```

Then only test2 will be shown. This is only happening on some specific computers (three located at the moment).

Is there some limitation to what can be run inside of  powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden { }? But if there is, why every other machine is running it no problem?

Every powershell is on the same version below

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.1682
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.1682
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Comment: This is a common question.  I think you have to run powershell with wscript, run with intWindowStyle 0.

Comment: No, the problem is not the flashing screen, the problem is that everything inside the powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden { } is just skipped, it doesn't run as if there isn't anything there. It's odd because on almost all computers the code runs as expected. I don't know if that's clear or not.

Comment: Multiple lines won't work unless you're inside another powershell.

Comment: the thing is the code runs fine on most computers (around 80 computers) with several lines, but on those 3 computers it won't run. It's an file.ps1 that has that code inside, so it's being called from another powershell script if that's what you meant

Comment: Based on all you've stated, this is not a PS-specific issue/PS-specific code issue; it's an environmental one on those hosts.

Comment: Don't use ISE :)  How are you usually running the file?  Do you open a PowerShell prompt and run the script from there, running it always from ISE, right-clicking on the file from explorer and running from the context menu, etc?

Comment: I run it from task scheduler when user logon. Is there a way to check if it's an environmental issue? How could I "repair" it?

Comment: From the task, what is the exact commandline/arguments that you are using.  Are you calling a ps1 script file (e.g., `powershell.exe -File myscriptfile.ps1`) or are you doing something similar to what you've shown us supplying powershell.exe with the commands inline (e.g. `powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -Command "Write-Host 'test'; Write-Host 'test1'"`)?

Comment: I'm calling it using `powershell.exe -File myscriptfile.ps1`. If I click on the file and then go to "run with powershell" it fails, also, if I copy the entire code inside of powershell.exe and run it also fails. Even if I do something like `powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden {
write-host "test"
write-host "test1"
}` on powershell it will fail, it just don't run what is inside of the { }

Comment: In myscriptfile.ps1 do you have something similar to your example where you call powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden { ... }?  Inside of the ps1 file you should not have have this.  It is unnecessary.  Just keep the code that is inside the braces.  As for why something like `powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden { write-host "test" write-host "test1" }` is not working, it's because using the scriptblock { } will only work when you are calling powershell from within a powershell session but not, for example, from a cmd session.  Same for task scheduler.

Comment: From task scheduler or cmd you would need to enter the command(s) to be run in double-quotes `powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden -command "write-host """test"""; write-host """test1""" "` and escape any double-quotes used inside or use single-quotes instead

Comment: Have a look here -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1#-command --  if you want to continue using the scriptblock you have to call it by adding & in front of it `powershell.exe  "& { write-host """test"""; write-host """test1""" }"`

Comment: One more thing I forgot to mention. Depending on the [PowerShell execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.2) set (or unset) on the computer running the code you may also want to consider adding the -ExecutionPolicy Bypass argument to the command `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -WindowStyle Hidden -NoProfile -Command "Write-Host ....."`

Comment: Nothing worked... I just reinstalled windows on their computers and it worked now. It was probably something related to a bad install maybe...